# Get dynamic contents of URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I use MWFeedParser to return stories from BBC News' RSS feed. They return the following, as an example:

```
item: MWFeedItem: “Woman guilty of family fire killings” - 2013-04-30 15:04:31 +0000
identifier: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-22294592
title: Woman guilty of family fire killings
link: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-22294592#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa
date: 2013-04-30 15:04:31 +0000
updated: (null)
summary: A woman is convicted of murdering five members of a neighbouring family, including three children, by starting a house fire.
content: (null)
enclosures: (null)
```

Going to either of those links returns the article, as so:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-22294592

I want to get the image and article content from that page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You've already taken the first step: you know that the article is at http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-22294592. So you download the content from that page and parse it.